# Как в webpack правильно настроить modulesDirectories?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Файловая структра:

```
app/
    components/
        ...
        Button/
            Button.jsx
webpack.config.js
```

Я хотел бы иметь возможность подключать этот компонент в другом компоненте без относительного пути, т.е. не так:

```
var Button = require('../Button/Button.jsx);
```

а вот так:

```
var Button = require('Button/Button.jsx);
```

Для этого в webpack есть наcтройка `resolve.modulesDirectories`, но как ее правильно настроить не совсем понятно. Пробовал так:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['web_modules', 'node_modules', 'components']
}
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['web_modules', 'node_modules', './app/components']
}
```

но не работает.

Comment: Если компонент один, то можно сделать `resolve: {alias: {"MyButton": "./app/components/Button/Button.jsx"}}`, и затем `require("MyButton");`